# How can I add extra space at the begining of a PE file section? (Windows API)

Tags: winapi, masm, portable-executable

I'm working with a patcher program and I want to add extra space at the begining of the .text section. Like if the PE section at disk(raw) begins with let's say 90 90 90 EB 64 ... etc I want to make it to begin with let's say **00 00 00 90** 90 90 90 EB 64 ... Can this be done using the windows api in c or asm? how can be done?

I'm using the function createfile to open the file and mapview to map it into memory(both functions from win api) and I'm working with MASM

I know that I can increase the file size by calling the CreateFile function and setting a larger file space but how can the specific .text section can be increased?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Win32 API that will handles this for you. You will have to actually parse the file's PE header and all of its sections yourself:

[Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

Open the existing file for input and create a new file for output. Parse the input file's PE, writing out everything that precedes the `.text` section, then write out the extra spacing as needed, then write out the `.text` section and everything that follows it. And make sure you are updating any RVAs throughout the PE that refer to memory addresses within/after the extra spacing you add, since you are changing the offset of those addresses.

When finished, replace the input file with the output file (preferably after backing it up first).

Comment: ... Update RVAs, .relocs and all instructions using rip relative addressing if necessary.